# ldap_search_ext_s: No such object error

Tags: c, ldap

How get info about people after connecting anonymously to server.

I am searching uid=barbara to anonymously binded ldap server as follow,

I get error,

```
LDAP initialize successful.
Set LDAPv3 client version.
LDAP connection successful.
ldap_search_ext_s: No such object
```

if i chnage 
char *FIND_DN  = " ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com";

rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld,root_dn ,root_pw);
It works fine.
code below:

```
int main(int argc, char**argv) 
{
 LDAP *ld;
 int desired_version = LDAP_VERSION3;
 char *ldap_host     = "localhost";
 char *root_dn       = "cn=Manager, dc=example,dc=com";
 char *root_pw       = "secret";
 char *FIND_DN  = "dc=example, dc=com";

 LDAPMessage  *result, *e;
 BerElement   *ber;
 char         *a;
 char         **vals;
 int          i, rc;

 ldap_initialize( &ld, ldap_host );
 printf("LDAP initialize successful.\n");

 rc = ldap_set_option(ld, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, &desired_version);
 if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {
    perror( "ldap_set_option failed" );
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 } else {
    printf("Set LDAPv3 client version.\n");
 }

 rc = ldap_simple_bind_s(ld,NULL ,NULL);
 if ( rc != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ldap_simple_bind_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc));
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 } else {
    printf("LDAP connection successful.\n");
 }

 if ( ( rc = ldap_search_ext_s( ld, FIND_DN, LDAP_SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                "(uid=barbara)",NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,
                                LDAP_NO_LIMIT, &result ) ) != LDAP_SUCCESS ) {

     fprintf(stderr, "ldap_search_ext_s: %s\n", ldap_err2string(rc));
     ldap_unbind( ld );
     return( 1 );
 }
 ldap_msgfree( result );
 ldap_unbind( ld );

 return( 0 );
}
```

On ldapsearch command ,i get

```
Enter LDAP Password:

# Users, example.com

dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

ou: Users

description: Example.Com Users 

objectClass: organizationalUnit

# matt, Users, example.com

dn: uid=matt,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

ou: Users

uid: matt

cn: Matt Butcher

sn: Butcher

givenName: Matt

givenName: Matthew

displayName: Matt Butcher

title: Systems Integrator

description: Systems Integration and IT for Example.Com

employeeType: Employee

departmentNumber: 001

employeeNumber: 001-08-98

mail: mbutcher@example.com

mail: matt@example.com

roomNumber: 301

telephoneNumber: +1 555 555 4321

mobile: +1 555 555 6789

st: Illinois

l: Chicago

street: 1234 Cicero Ave.

homePhone: +1 555 555 9876

homePostalAddress: 1234 home street $ Chicago, IL $ 60699-1234

userPassword:: c2VjcmV0

preferredLanguage: en-us,en-gb

objectClass: person

objectClass: organizationalPerson

objectClass: inetOrgPerson

# barbara, Users, example.com

dn: uid=barbara,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com

ou: Users

uid: barbara

sn: Jensen

cn: Barbara Jensen

givenName: Barbara

displayName: Barbara Jensen

mail: barbara@example.com

userPassword:: c2VjcmV0

objectClass: person

objectClass: organizationalPerson

objectClass: inetOrgPerson


# search result

search: 2

result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 4

# numEntries: 3
```

Comment: And there is a `"barbara"` in the directory?

Comment: I have added result for ldapsearch command , Please check the content of my directory. if you need more info .tell me